# How will an existing Office 365 student subscription interact with a subscription from a laptop purchase?

Tags: office-365

I've previously purchased a Student copy of Office 365, which was a one time price for 4 years. This gives me a subscription through ~2018 .

Say I now purchase a laptop or tablet that ["includes" a year subscription](http://www.neowin.net/news/hp-reveals-super-cheap-windows-laptops-starting-at-200-tablets-at-100) (and perks like 1TB of space).

Do these subscriptions:

- overlap (I'm subscribed through ~2018, with 1TB of storage)
- stack (I'd be good through ~2019, with 2TB of storage)
- not mesh at all (Student is good for 2 computers for 4 years... I know purchased 365 is good for 5 computers for 1 year... I'm not sure how those two would "combine" OR something like this that is included with the purchase of a laptop)

I've included a link to a HP story, but I would assume other tablet/laptop/computers will offer the same offer. Are there different versions of the same offer? How do you "combine" these different offers if I purchase a laptop from company A, tablet from company B, phone from C and a student subscription from mycoolege.edu?